# Android: Is there a way to tell what device your app is running on

Tags: android

My app is crashing on the new Samsung Galaxy smart phones.  I was wondering if there is a way to detect if it is running on these phones?  (So the Galaxy phones would not run the code that causes them to crash, but the remaining smart phones would run it)

Comment: I do not think its only model-dependent, maybe its the Android-Version. Also in the Android Developers Console you can define what devices are supported and what are not. Maybe you post more info about the crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a number of constants in the [`android.os.Build`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) package than can help with what you are looking for. In particular there is a `MODEL` constant which refers to the name of the product.